# How to setup Android Chrome to translate highlighted text via the pop-up Google search?

Tags: popup, google-translate

How to set up the little pop-up bar down below the screen, which generates a quick Google search whenever a word or phrase has been highlighted, to automatically translate what has been selected. That was my original setup but I guess I have messed up some settings and now it doesn't translate. How can I turn it back on?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Google Translate's settings.
2. Select "Tap to Translate", then enable "Enable".
3. In Preferred languages, set "Your primary language" and "Language you translate the most".
4. Go back to Chrome, select a word, "Translate" should appear. Click on it to translate the word.

**Update**

Based on Vadim's comment that the method might no longer work, to get the translation back:

1. Enter `chrome://flags` on your search bar
2. Type `translation` on the Search flag box
3. Set `Contextual Search translations` to Enabled.
4. Then Relaunch Chrome

You should be able again to see the translation at the bottom after selecting a word as seen on the image below.

[image: IMG:]

**Remarks:**

- `Touch to Search` must be enabled in Chrome's settings (Settings -> Sync and Google services -> Touch to search)
- There are times when it stops working. You need either:

  a. pressing the 3-dot then Translate or

  b. to restart Chrome, or

Comment: It worked even without Google translate installed on my device - until the beginning of 2020. But now I still can’t get it back. Your answer doesn’t seem to address the specific problem, at least for me: I still can’t get that popup bar below the screen back.

Comment: @VadimSamokhin See edit.

Comment: Thanks, Reddy, I really appreciate your help, but still no luck :(

Comment: @VadimSamokhin Does the Google logo appears when you select a word when not using my workaround? If you have Google Translate installed, the only remaining solution is to select Translate from the menu that appears after selecting a word. The wors will be translated on the Google Translate bubble but not on the bottom bar.

Comment: I've ended up with exactly that option: I choose "translate" from the menu that appears after selecting a word. Thanks much for your help!